# How to check in using Facebook's mobile site?

Tags: facebook

I am using Android. Without a Facebook app, is it possible to check in via http://m.facebook.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

> **How do I check in to a Place on my mobile device?**
>
> 1. Tap [image: FB Menu]
> 2. Select [image: FB Neqarby] Nearby
> 3. Tap Check In (top-right corner)
> 4. Tap a nearby place or type the name of the place in the search bar
> 5. Write a caption, tag friends, or add a photo
> 6. Tap Post

Taken from [this Facebook FAQ Article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=174846215904356#How-do-I-check-in-to-a-Place-on-my-smart-phone-or-another-mobile-device?)